# Equation of Trajectory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, newtonian-mechanics, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

I was reading about Lorentz force law and motion of a charged particle under Electric field or magnetic field and I understood how they move in it.

But as I was moving further I came across the principle of a "velocity filter",
where they kept $\vec B,\vec v,\vec E$ mutually perpendicular, and then setting $|F_e|$ equal and opposite to $|F_m|$. So that,
$qE=qvB$ $\implies$ $v=\dfrac{E}{B}$
And that's good too, not a problem.

But then something popped up in my mind, what would happen and how would a particle move if,
$|F_e|\neq|F_m|$ and maybe if they are even in same direction.

So, I run some thought experiment and came to a conclusion or imagery about the path of the particle being something like this, well maybe?(Sorry for bad drawing, took time to draw anyhow.)

[image: Sorry for the bad drawing, I am not too good with it ^^]

Now, I had the picture of the particle moving but I wanted to find an exact equation of trajectory for it.

**Numerical part(my attempt):**

I knew the magnetic field would try to put the charge particle in a circle and Electric field would try to distort it toward right as shown in fig. Therefore, I resorted to use vector algebra for analysis to find the individual effect of each field and add them.

1) **Magnetic field**
For circle, the equation was simple,

> $\vec r_m=r \cos(t)\hat i+r\sin(t)\hat j$ ;
>    Where r denote the radius of circle, t any parameter.
>   (*Note that I assume the the path is in x,y plane as indicated by the unit vector which is not shown in the figure.*)

2)**Electric field**
It was hard to figure out , but I came up with this equation.

> $\vec r_e=ct\hat i$,
>   where c is any constant related to motion of particle in electric field.
>   (*And I really have no intuitive sense as to why it is not $c$ or maybe $ct^2$, it somehow agreed with the curve i thought and somehow it seemed the correct one.*)

Hence
3)**Net result**

> $\vec r=(r\cos(t)+ct)\hat i+r\sin(t)\hat j$

Converting into Cartesian form we get,

> $x=r\cos(t)+ct$ and $y=r\sin t$

After shifting, tweaking the curve and graphing I got this,

> $x=r-r\cos(t)+ct$ and $y=r\sin(t)$

Here's a graph of what it looks like, very similar to that of figure drawn.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3djbngtups

**Questions based on above observation:**

1. Is the equation i derived correct and what would be a proper derivation?
   I tried to determine $r$ by assuming the equation that $F=Bqv$ and the
       initial condition that magnetic field $\vec B$ alone should prove
       the necessary centripetal force to put the particle in a circle of
       radius $r$.   Giving,
       $Bqv=\dfrac{mv^2}{r}$ $\implies$
       $r=\dfrac{mv}{Bq}$
       However, for $c$ , I have no idea. And also I am not sure if $r$ is
       correct or not?
2. What would happen if $\vec B ,\vec v,\vec E$ are not
       even perpendicular? For e.g., $\vec v$ inclined to some axis with $\vec B$.

Comment: Perhaps you should break up your question into a few separate ones. Right now, there is just *too much* at the same time.

Comment: Actually , the upper part is just my attempt and I wanted to explain what exactly was I doing. The questions I have asked are in short only two as I have edited now. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've derived the equation you're looking for.  You can skip down to the SUMMARY section if you don't want to see the math.

You need to start with the equation of motion:

$\vec{F} = m \vec{a} = m \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}~~~$
(using the fact that the acceleration is the time derivative of the velocity)

Where the force $\vec{F}$ on the particle is given by the Lorentz force:

$\vec{F} = q(\vec{E} + \vec{v} \times \vec{B})$

Using the coordinate system in your picture,

$\vec{E} = E~ \hat{y}$

$\vec{B} = B~ \hat{x}$

$\vec{v(t)} = v_x ~ \hat{x} + v_y ~ \hat{y} + v_z ~ \hat{z}$

Putting that all together, we have:

$m \frac{d}{dt}(v_x ~ \hat{x} + v_y ~ \hat{y} + v_z ~ \hat{z}) = q[E~ \hat{y} + (v_x ~ \hat{x} + v_y ~ \hat{y} + v_z ~ \hat{z}) \times (B~ \hat{x})]$

Expanding and simplifying...

$m \frac{d v_x}{dt} ~ \hat{x} + m \frac{d v_y}{dt} ~ \hat{y} + m \frac{d v_z}{dt} ~ \hat{z} = q E~ \hat{y} + q B (v_z ~ \hat{y} - v_y \hat{z})$

We can separate this equation into three separate equations, one for each component of $\hat{v}$

$\frac{d v_x}{dt} = 0$

$\frac{d v_y}{dt} = \frac{q}{m} E + \frac{q}{m} B v_z$

$\frac{d v_z}{dt} = -\frac{q}{m} B v_y$

The x-component equation above tells us that in this situation the x-component of the velocity (the one parallel to the $\vec{B}$) is constant:

$v_x(t) = v_{x0}$

And therefore the x-coordinate is a linear function of time.  In your drawing, it looks like the x velocity is zero, so the x-coordinate is a constant, which we will take to be 0 for simplicity:

$x(t) = 0$

The second and third equations are unfortunately coupled, but they can be easily solved by taking the derivative of the entire y-component equation, and substituting in for $\frac{d v_z}{dt}$ using the z-component equation:

$\frac{d^2 v_y}{dt^2} = \frac{q}{m} B \frac{d v_z}{dt}$

$\frac{d^2 v_y}{dt^2} = \frac{q}{m} B (-\frac{q}{m} B v_y)$

$\frac{d^2 v_y}{dt^2} = - \frac{q^2}{m^2} B^2 v_y$

The solution to this 2nd order differential equation is

$v_y = v_0 sin(\frac{q}{m} B t)$

Using this and the above equations we can find $v_z$:

$v_z = v_0 cos(\frac{q}{m} B t) - \frac{E}{B}$

Integrating these to get the components of the particle's position:

$y(t) = - \frac{m}{q B} v_0 cos(\frac{q}{m} B t)$

$z(t) = \frac{m}{q B} v_0 sin(\frac{q}{m} B t) - \frac{E}{B} t$

---

**SUMMARY:**

A particle in perpendicular magnetic and electric fields with uniform strength B and E respectively moving with an initial velocity of $\vec{v} = v_0 ~ \hat{z}$ has the following position over time:

$x(t) = 0$

$y(t) = - \frac{m}{q B} v_0 cos(\frac{q}{m} B t)$

$z(t) = \frac{m}{q B} v_0 sin(\frac{q}{m} B t) - \frac{E}{B} t$

So you were correct about the value of "r" - it's $\frac{m}{q B} v_0$, and the value of "c" that you were looking for is $\frac{E}{B}$.

HOWEVER:  Interestingly, the "drift" velocity which causes the sort of spiralling shape is NOT along the direction of the electric field, but instead counterintuitively perpendicular to both the electric and magnetic fields!  In plasma physics, this is known as the "$E \times B$ drift"

Comment: Amazing answer and explanation!  Thank you. I wish I could vote up too , but I am still 3 points in physics forum.